# ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi

I am trying to `ssh` into a raspberry pi 3 from an Ubuntu 18.04 machine but kept getting this error:

```
ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection refused
```

The raspberry pi uses an Ethernet connection for internet. I have done the following:

1. I have also enabled ssh on the Pi 3 through `raspi-config` and through the Raspberry Pi Configuration
2. I have edited the sshd_config file on the Raspberry Pi

   - set the default port to port 22
   - set `PasswordAunthenticaton` to yes
   - set `PermitRootLogin` to yes
3. On the Pi 3, I have uninstalled and reinstalled `ssh` and `openssh-server` multiple times and perform step 2 with no results.

Can I get help for I'm at my wits end here

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, and you mention uninstalling ssh/openssh-server, but no mention of re-installing them???

Comment: edited the question to reflect more info. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you ping the pi?

Comment: The issue is with the ssh server (ie. pi)  in my opinion, and thus that is the OS/release info I was interested in, and is still unknown

Comment: yes i can ping the pi

Comment: @guiverc The pi is running the latest Raspbian and the PC is running an up to date Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Did you open port 22 in your firewall? Easiest to install `gufw` and do it that way.

Comment: yes, I opened port 22 and installed gufw